# Share GPU between two slurm job steps

Tags: scheduler, slurm

How can i share GPU between two job steps in SLURM, i can share CPU between two steps but not the GPU.

````
srun --pty --gpus=1  bash
compute-node-11:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Feb 16 22:42:47 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   36C    P0    44W / 160W |      0MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

srun --pty   --jobid=1164 bash
srun: Job 1164 step creation temporarily disabled, retrying```
````

Even i tried **--oversubscribe** but still same issue. is it not possible to share GPU b/w two steps ?